# Spring boot Flyway Gradle dependency version auto inclusion

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, build.gradle, flyway, postgresql-9.6

I am using *Spring boot 2.7.5* and included dependency *Flyway core 7.15.0* to execute migrations script on Psotgresql-9.6 but The IntelliJ-Idea external dependencies show  *Flyway core dependency 7.15.0* and *Flyway core dependency 8.5.3* which I never mentioned in any of my *gradle.build* file ,how can I exclude this

**Migration module gradle.build**

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra")
    implementation("org.cognitor.cassandra:cassandra-migration-spring-boot-starter:2.5.0_v4")
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.15.0'
}
```

External dependencies view
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a transitive dependency.
For instance, if you have a multi-module Project, that might be a dependency of one of the Modules.
IDEA offers a lot of options to [analyze dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-analysis.html) in your Project, see if any of those would be helpful for you.
You can also run "gradle dependencies" from command prompt if you are looking for the raw Gradle output.

If you're specifically looking to exclude a dependency - refer to [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html).